# How to split a row in a multiple row in R

Tags: r, split

I have a dataset like this:

```
a <- c("a","b", "c", "d")

b <- c(7, 5, 4, 3)

c <- c("ABc","D", "EF", "BCEEF")

m <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

my expected result is:

```
a1 <- c("a","a","a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d")

b1 <- c(7, 7, 7,5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3)

c1 <- c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "B", "C", "EE", "F")

m1 <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1)
```

at the moment I developed this code:

```
library(tidyr)

separate_rows(m ,c, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)")
```

In this way I create a row for every letter in c column, but when I have a double letter I want the two letter in the same row
like this:

How can I solve?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can try

```
m %>%
    mutate(c = regmatches(c, gregexpr("(\\w)(\\1+)?", c))) %>%
    unnest(c)
```

or

```
m %>%
    mutate(c = str_extract_all(c, "(\\w)(\\1+)?")) %>%
    unnest(c)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   a         b c
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1 a         7 A
 2 a         7 B
 3 a         7 c
 4 b         5 D
 5 c         4 E
 6 c         4 F
 7 d         3 B    
 8 d         3 C
 9 d         3 EE
10 d         3 F
```

Comment: how can I do the opposite? I mean, if I start from dataset m1, how can I obtain dataset m?

Comment: @Boh You can use `aggregate(c~., m1, paste0, collapse = "")`

Answer (score 0):

After your call to `separate_rows()` you could group by run length id, collapsing over identical letters, and take the distinct rows:

```
separate_rows(m ,c, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)") %>% 
  group_by(id = data.table::rleid(a,b,c)) %>%
  reframe(a,b,c = paste0(c,collapse="")) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Output:

```
      id a         b c    
   <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1 a         7 A    
 2     2 a         7 B    
 3     3 a         7 c    
 4     4 b         5 D    
 5     5 c         4 E    
 6     6 c         4 F    
 7     7 d         3 B    
 8     8 d         3 C    
 9     9 d         3 EE   
10    10 d         3 F
```